# Need to find best date and time picker in angular 6

Tags: datepicker, angular6

I have a angular project with this configuration.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 10.16.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.3
@angular/cdk                      7.2.1
@angular/cli                      6.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.3
@schematics/update                0.6.3
rxjs                              6.0.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

I need best date and time picker for my project.

I have already used [datetime picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime). But I got issue in `prod` build.

[Issue](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker/issues/575)

To prevent this issue I have to upgrade the npm version and it requires `typescript` 3+ version. 
When I update the `typescript` version I got error in `ng serve`.

Need : I have a date min, max validations in my app. So I need stable version which gives me this types of features.

**Features :**

```
- Min Date
- Max Date 
- Pick time only 
- Set the value (Patch value)
- Support reactive form
```

Can any one share any npm module link ?

Comment: What angular version were you using and what package did you go with? I'm in Angular 6 and been looking all day for a Date & Time picker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngx-bootstrap has a great date picker, here is a demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker

and the docs

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

or Angular Material has a datepicker

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll look into that.

Comment: I have check all the examples. And just one thing is remain to choose the time. If that feature is also there then can you please share the link?

Comment: I have never used a time picker sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Best for me is

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime

as i am not using `bootstrap`